# Generate number in certain range from current date of device in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am looking for solution in Swift 3 where my app will generate random number from current date in the range <0;1000>.

For example I would love to get something like this:

```
14/2/2017 -> 323
15/2/2017 -> 25
16/2/2017 -> 898
...
```

If I remember right in Java I was able to generate same number each time by using certain seed in my random number generator which allowed me to generate same number all the time. I was thinking about using value of year+month+day as the seed to generate same number for all the users that will use app at the same day.

Java:

```
seed = currentYear + currentMonth + currentDay
Random generator = new Random(seed);
double random = generator.nextDouble();
...
```

Please help me to solve that problem in Swift 3, I have tried to go through all arc4random and other random functions and I didn't found any solution.

Comment: If you just add the month, day, and year you are going to get the same seeds repeating 11/2/2017 and 12/1/2017 would have the same seed, for example. I suggest using `year*365+month*31+day` as the seed to `srand48()`

Comment: Actually it should be `year * 372 + month * 31 + day` to get unique seeds, as we assuming that every month have maximum 31 days, then 31 * 12 = **372**.

Comment: So you may end up with solution similar to the following [code example](https://gist.github.com/vkelembet/3c4e10361f7511b408a29ec44cf590fe)

Comment: Thanks for code example Volodymyr! I have used it in my project and it works exactly as I wanted.